# virtualhosts usernames length

Tags: domain, virtualhost

We operated a dedicated server a while back, and every account had a "temporary link" that looked like this:

`http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/~sometext`

`~sometext` was limited at 8 characters I believe.

We also have a resellers account with our hosting provider, and the account names for this look like this:

`http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/thedomainname.co.uk` - but with no character limits.

I much prefer this style (even if just for aesthetic reasons).

Is there some kind of Apache module that allows for longer user names?

Hope I've been clear enough

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some kind of Apache module that allows for longer user names?

Apache (mod_userdir) does not intrinsically restrict the number of characters in the username. Constraints will be inherited from the underlying OS though - IIRC there was an old POSIX standard for 8 chars - check your limits.h file.

> Hope I've been clear enough

Still some points I'm not getting.

You're asking bout virtualhosts - but the difference between the URLs is at the path level - not the vhost.

The '~' in the URL tells the webserver to use the mod_userdir mapping to find the files - but that's omited from the second example implying that the URL mapping has nothing to do with mod_userdir. This might simply be a directory name - or it might be re-written by mod_rewrite, or it may be a directory alias.